# Design Patterns in Jhipster

Tags: design-patterns, jhipster

When creating a system, we may use design patterns like singleton, observer, fascade, JavaEE design patterns(MVC/MVVC) and etc. So what are the built in design patterns in jhipster core module?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can say that the design pattern used in JHipster is MVC (depending on how you use it)

In the backend if you use service class :

- RestController is the View.
- Service is the controller where the logic of your code is.
- The repositories are the model of your application.

Almost the same for the front-end :

- Views are the html files
- Controllers are the controller
- And the services are the model